# How to use multiple different localStorage in a single domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website in which there are 3 different folders to be accessed by 3 different users. say if you accessed www.thissite.com/folder1/index.html it will check if user is logged and redirect to login page if not.

I used localStorage to do so since i don't want to deal with cookies and session because of IOS issues.

I have this code that assigns a default object to localStorage. It work fine for single folder. but when i try to use it on other folders it's going directly to the lading page of the folder and not calling login page.

How can i use the similar code with localStorage for different folder? How can i make 3 unique localStorage for each folder so when accessed will still be protected and ask for login?

Here's my code:

**index.html**

```
             if(localStorage['data']){
             var data=JSON.parse(localStorage['data']);
             if(data.logedIn==1){

             }else{
              location.href="http://example.com/test/login.html";
             }
            }
            var folder1 = "http://example.com/test/";

            var defaultInfo=[
             {folder:'folder1',count:1,pageLoadCount:1},
            ],
            data=localStorage['data']?      JSON.parse(localStorage['data']):defaultInfo;//load

            console.log(data);

            if(data.pageLoadCount==0){
             location.href="http://example.com/test/login.html";
            }

            data.pageLoadCount++;
            data.count=dir1.pageLoadCount;

            localStorage['data']=JSON.stringify(data);
```

login.html

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function test() {
            var userName = document.Form1.id.value;
            var password = document.Form1.pass.value;
            if ((userName=="moulinex") && (password=="abc123")) {

                window.open("http://example.com/test/index.html");

                } else {
                alert("Invalid ID or Password!")
                }
            }

            </script>
```

i place this on the below of login page

```
    <script>
            localStorage['data']=JSON.stringify({logedIn:1})
            </script>
```

Thanks a lot in advance. All/any answer is very much apprecaited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalsStorage is name/value dictionary. If you just use the `data` name, you will override any previous values in it. Instead, use three different names (one for each folder) and set their data that way:

```
localStorage['folder1'] = JSON.strinfify({logedIn:1});
localStorage['folder2'] = JSON.strinfify({logedIn:0});
localStorage['folder3'] = JSON.strinfify({logedIn:1});
```

Alternatively, you could just create one object into localStorage and populate the different folders that way.

```
localSotrage['data'] = JSON.stringify({
                          folder1: {logedIn: 1}, 
                          folder2: {logedIn: 0}, 
                          folder3: {logedIn: 1}
                       });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. SO instead of using `var defaultInfo=[{folder:'folder1',count:1,pageLoadCount:1},],` shall i use `localStorage['folder1'] = JSON.strinfify({logedIn:1});
localStorage['folder2'] = JSON.strinfify({logedIn:0});
localStorage['folder3'] = JSON.strinfify({logedIn:1});` ?

Comment: if i use the first set of codes, shall i have it all on each page? or just `localStorage['folder1'] = JSON.strinfify({logedIn:1});` for folder1 and distbute others? thanks again

Comment: Since you need to know the information on all pages, I would just stick it into one object so you don't have to make 3 different calls to the localStorage. It also is much cleaner that way IMO.

Comment: i tired it like this `if(localStorage['data']){
 var data=JSON.parse(localStorage['data']);
 if(data.logedIn==1){
  
 }else{
  location.href="http://example.com/test/login.html";
 }
}

var folder1 = "http://example.com/test/";

localSotrage['data'] = JSON.stringify({folder1: {logedIn: 1}, folder2: {logedIn: 0}, folder3: {logedIn: 1}});

console.log(data);

if(data.pageLoadCount==0){
 location.href="http://example.com/test/login.html";
}

data.pageLoadCount++;
data.count=dir1.pageLoadCount;

localStorage['data']=JSON.stringify(data);`

Comment: the problem is it's going straight to the ladning page of the folder wherein it should first call the login page since user is not loged in. can you please help me fix what im doing wrong with this code? thanks again

Comment: you need to access the right `logedIn` variable of the folder: `if (data.folder1.logedIn === 1)`

Comment: i made it like this. still not redirecting `if(localStorage['data']){
 var data=JSON.parse(localStorage['data']);
 if(data.logedIn==1){
  
 }else{
  location.href="http://example.com/test/login.html";
 }}
var folder1 = "http://example.com/test/";
localSotrage['data'] = JSON.stringify({folder1: {logedIn: 1}, folder2: {logedIn: 0}, folder3: {logedIn: 1}});

console.log(data);
if (data.folder1.logedIn === 1){
if(data.pageLoadCount==0){
 location.href="http://example.com/test/login.html";
}

data.pageLoadCount++;
data.count=dir1.pageLoadCount;
localStorage['data']=JSON.stringify(data);
}`